# Why split and readlines break for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

In our Python course, we were given this problem. We need to get accounts data from a file, perform some manipulations, and output the results...
I've tried to use the first value of the account as an initial minimum. It's not working. It does something I have no idea and just shuts off entire `for` loop.

`accounts.txt` is a file that stores ID, savings type, and value. For example,

```
66096   d   873323
29615   c   849977
45387   s   186640
95384   c   933363
13615   c   733321
46396   c   714610
17428   s   833671
43730   d   308296
92061   c   670423
51798   c   156063
58083   s   940510
```

So, here's the code:

```py
file=open('accounts.txt',mode='r')
linep=file.readlines()
mins=linep[0].split()[2]
sumc=0
maxc=0
sums=0
sumd=0
avrd=0
cntr=0
for i in file:
    if i.split()[1]=='c':
        sumc+=int(i.split()[2])
        if int(i.split()[2])>=maxc:
            maxc=int(i.split()[2])
    elif i.split()[1]=='s':
        sums+=int(i.split()[2])
        if int(i.split()[2])<=mins:
            mins=int(i.split()[2])
    elif i.split()[1]=='d':
        sumd+=int(i.split()[2])
        cntr+=1
avrd=sums/cntr
print('The sum of all checking accounts is:',sumc)
print('The sum of all saving accounts is:',sums)
print('The sum of all deposit accounts is:',sumd)
print('The maximum balance for all checking accounts is:',maxc)
print('The minimum balance for all savings accounts is:',mins)
print('The average balance for all deposit accounts is:',avrd)
```

It works when you set the `mins=99999999999`, but I don't think that's a good solution.

Well, the output should've been like this:

```py
The sum of all checking accounts is: 209315463
The sum of all saving accounts is: 50272914
The sum of all deposit accounts is: 19976046
The maximum balance for all checking accounts is: 998992
The minimum balance for all savings accounts is: 150
The average balance for all deposit accounts is: 554890.1666666666
```

But 2nd & 3rd lines screw everything up, so I have this

```py
The sum of all checking accounts is: 0
The sum of all saving accounts is: 0
The sum of all deposit accounts is: 0
The maximum balance for all checking accounts is: 0
The minimum balance for all savings accounts is: 873323
```

So, what do you think? I know, you can use min and max, but that's college we are talking about. They want to do it this way.

Comment: You seem to be iterating over the file, but only after `linep=file.readlines()` which will have read the entire file. Thus there will be nothing left for the `for` loop.

Comment: Try replacing for "i in file:" with for "i in linep:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal changes to correct your code

```
file=open('accounts.txt',mode='r')
linep=file.readlines()
mins=int(linep[0].split()[2])  # Need to make int
sumc=0
maxc=0
sums=0
sumd=0
avrd=0
cntr=0
for i in linep:  # need to loop over linep not file
    if i.split()[1]=='c':
        sumc+=int(i.split()[2])
        if int(i.split()[2])>=maxc:
            maxc=int(i.split()[2])
    elif i.split()[1]=='s':
        sums+=int(i.split()[2])
        if int(i.split()[2])<=mins:
            mins=int(i.split()[2])
    elif i.split()[1]=='d':
        sumd+=int(i.split()[2])
        cntr+=1
avrd=sums/cntr
print('The sum of all checking accounts is:',sumc)
print('The sum of all saving accounts is:',sums)
print('The sum of all deposit accounts is:',sumd)
print('The maximum balance for all checking accounts is:',maxc)
print('The minimum balance for all savings accounts is:',mins)
print('The average balance for all deposit accounts is:',avrd)
```

Code Refactoring (simpler and more efficient)

```
file=open('accounts.txt',mode='r')
linep=file.readlines()
data = [x.split() for x in linep]
checking = [int(x[2]) for x in data if x[1] == 'c']
savings = [int(x[2]) for x in data if x[1] == 's']
deposits = [int(x[2]) for x in data if x[1] == 'd']
sumc, sums, sumd = sum(checking), sum(savings), sum(deposits)
maxc, mins, avrd = max(checking), min(savings), sum(deposits)/len(deposits)
print('The sum of all checking accounts is:',sumc)
print('The sum of all saving accounts is:',sums)
print('The sum of all deposit accounts is:',sumd)
print('The maximum balance for all checking accounts is:',maxc)
print('The minimum balance for all savings accounts is:',mins)
print('The average balance for all deposit accounts is:',avrd)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a lot better, thank you. But, why exactly looping over file breaks it?

Comment: @Sanzhik what do you mean by "looping over file breaks"?  Are you asking about: data = [x.split() for x in linep]?

Comment: difference between "file" and "linep". What's the difference between using one over the other?

Comment: @Sanzhik "open" just returns a file object which you use to access the file for either reading or writing.  It does not read the data.  "readlines" is where the file is actually read.  Check the output of 1) print(file) vs.
2) print(file.readlines()).  For more details check online resources such as: https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html